# Google tag manager event macro

Tags: google-analytics

I am reading this tuttorial: http://www.amazeemetrics.com/en/blog/google-tag-manager-guide-step-step-tutorial-event-tracking-part-1#comment-4024

It mentions {{event}} equals gtm.linkClick. How do I create macro like {{event}}? Is it a custom event type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{event}}` macro is a default macro that should have been created with the new container, but if it doesn't exist, you'll need to create the macro using the type `Custom Event`.

[image: Example macro setup]